# How to add extra column in aspnet_profile and make modifications in aspnet_Profile_SetProperties?

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

I am trying to add extra columns in asp table installed using aspnet_regsql.exe.

I am adding extra column in aspnet_profile table as causesID and did changes in the aspnet_Profile_SetProperties by adding additional parameter as @causesID.

I saw that there is a class named ProfileParameter and i did make use of that, my code is below,

```
ProfileParameter objParameter = new ProfileParameter();
                objParameter.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true;
                objParameter.DbType = DbType.Int32;
                objParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                objParameter.Name = "@CausesID";
                objParameter.PropertyName = "CausesId";
```

Here I did adding extra parameter to be passed to aspnet_Profile_SetProperties.
But I'm not sure this is correct or not.

In the stored procedure, i did some changes to installed stored procedure like this,

```
@causesID int  =>  for declaration of parameter
```

Here I added the extra parameter to be added to the aspnet_profile,

```
    UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Profile
            SET    PropertyNames=@PropertyNames, PropertyValuesString = @PropertyValuesString,
                   PropertyValuesBinary = @PropertyValuesBinary, LastUpdatedDate=@CurrentTimeUtc,CausesID=@CausesID  WHERE  UserId = @UserId

INSERT INTO dbo.aspnet_Profile(UserId, PropertyNames, PropertyValuesString, PropertyValuesBinary, LastUpdatedDate,CausesID)
             VALUES (@UserId, @PropertyNames, @PropertyValuesString, @PropertyValuesBinary, @CurrentTimeUtc,@CausesID)
```

In the aspnet_profile table, I added a column as causesID.

But it didn't work for me.

Please kindly advise me on that issue.

Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you not to mess with the internals of the Membership implementation but to use the possibilities of the profile ittself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I had some doubts in asp Profile, so can you pls tell me that, above method is possible in asp membership or not...so that i may move on to the next step instead of searching for the solution.

Comment: ProfileParameter class is used for what, whether it is useful or not..?